# Bridge table that join multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've a Product table and a Feature table that are joined together using a bridge table, ProductFeature.  Below are simplified version of these three tables.  These works fine.  No problem here.

```
[Table("Products")]
public partial class ProductEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductFeatureEntity> productFeatures {get; set;}
}

[Table("Features")]
public partial class FeatureEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductFeatureEntity> productFeatures {get; set;}
}

[Table("ProductFeatures")]
public partial class ProductFeatureEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }

    public int SequenceNbr {get; set;}

    public ProductEntity Product {get; set;}
    public FeatureEntity Feature {get; set;}
}
```

But now, I need to make that same bridge table to also be able to join the Product table itself.  Another word, I need to change from "Product can have multiple Features" to "Product can have multiple features and can also have multiple sub-product".  I need to use the same bridge table because I need to know the sequence, which is controlled by SequenceNbr field, of each features and sub-products.  Is it possible to do this in EF?

Answer (score 0):

you can add `ParentId` to `ProductEntity`
and use this in Configuration Class:

```
 HasMany(x => x.ProductEntity).WithOptional()
.HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId);
```

Or
Use this in `OnModelCreating` method in `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductEntity>()
.HasOptional().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.ParentId)
```

Comment: I think that is just to make it able to reference itself, which I'll lost sequencing ability.  In the ProductFeature table, it has a SequenceNbr field.  I need to be able to add product to that table.

Comment: this is for ProductEntity and you can make sub-product and fill ParentId.and every product or sub-product has ProductFeatureEntity and use SequenceNbr field.

Comment: How would I be able to know the sequence of the sub-product?  As mentioned, a product can have multi features and sub-products, and the sequence of each feature or sub-product that attached to a product is import.  For example, ProductA has Feature2 , Sub-product1, and Feature1.  In my process, for ProductA, it'll need to know that Feature2 come first, the next is Sub-Product1 and the next is Feature1